# Heavy components in ReactJS perform slow on IE browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have react component with large data-set, around 200 state variable defined in which I have store user specific data line name, mobile no, email etc. Also around 40 react component embedded in that single component. I have calculated time to set state for single variable is 290 millisecond in IE and it is calculated on Chrome is 66 millisecond. It means, it is taking more time to set state in IE browser. Can anyone help me around this? 
IE Version 11.0
Google Chrome Version 68.0

Here is the code of on change of mobile no field

```
handleMobileChange = (value) => {
        let error = this.state.errors; 
        error['Mobile'] = "";
        var regx = /^[789]([0-9])*$/;
        if(value.length >= 1){
            if(!regx.test(value)){ 
                return false; 
              }
              else{
                  value = value.trim();
                  this.setState({
                      Mobile: value,
                      errors:error
                  });
              }
        }else{
            value = '';
            this.setState({
                Mobile: value,
                errors:error
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to be much more specific. What do you store in the variables? What components do you use? What version of Internet Explorer? What version of Chrome? Is it fast in Chrome? 66ms for a single variable seems slow, especially given you have 200. Show your code.

Comment: E Version 11.0 Google Chrome Version 68.0 It is fast in Chrome. Added code above.